# gwt tomcat, where are my files saved ?

Tags: mysql, gwt, tomcat

First i want to appologize for my english skills because I'm a french dev ^^
I got a very simple problem with a gwt project. I want to get a picture from a database and save it on the server. When i run the project on eclipse, java save the picture on my war directory and that's fine.

Bue when i run the project on my tomcat server, java save me the picture on the directory where tomcat is...

that's pretty weird !

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: without posting the relevant pieces of code we will not be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each running application on a computer has a "current working directory" assigned to it. If you're not specifying the path where the file should be saved then it will be saved to the CWD by default. This CWD will vary depending on which container you use to run your application.

It's possible to change the CWD but this is not a good idea in case other parts of the container depend on it. You might like to add a [context-param](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters) to your web.xml so that you can specify a path where files will be saved.